# Update app when server update android

Tags: android

I created android app that connects with MySql in phpAdmin by Json code and the app works well with me. I want when the admin add a new row in the table that in server, the app knows that the new data added, meaning that I want the app updated with sever forever.

How to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a request to the server every once in a while or let have a REFRESH button in your app. For the request to the server use an AsyncTask and s

Inside onPostExecute update your UI.

[Check the AyncTask docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for Android and Push Notifications when ever you update your Mysql data, so that your app can connect to your server and download refreshed data accordingly, Saves Battery and improves your app performance.

Tutorial Here: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/